# Symfony2 console command

Tags: php, symfony, command-line, console

I followed Symfony2 [create a basic command line](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#creating-a-basic-command).

```
<?php
// application.php

use Acme\Command\GreetCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;

$application = new Application();
$application->add(new GreetCommand);
$application->run();
```

But I received the faltal Error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Application' not found

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/using_components.html you allways need to include autoload file.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/using_components.html, you need to include the autoloader at the top of your PHP script.

```
// update this to the path to the "vendor/"
// directory, relative to this file
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```